# Text is gone from python terminal output

Tags: python

I'm practising python and recently this problem crept up when I have invalid syntax in a program, the error output in terminal from python is blank like so..

```
 python test.py 
    File "test.py", line 6

                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: Please post the code segment that is generating this error. It is impossible to help without the culprit code.

Comment: I guess he's asking how to fix the Python terminal so that it shows the code of the line that has error, and caret below the problem area.

Comment: What IDE do you use? E.g. Raw terminal under Linux? X11? IDLE?

Comment: All terminals are doing this for me, the code doesnt matter, if i leave out a ) in a print statement it displays like this

Comment: Nevertheless, Windows, Linux, what else? It's a problem of your terminal emulator. Try e.g. IDLE (under Windows). This does it itself and therefore should display the complete error text and not overwrite it with the second line :)

Comment: Python displays this when you run the program in terminal that only contains print('Hello' without a closing )

Comment: @Amorpheus: This is due to the fact that the closing bracket could just as well be on the next line or the one after that or the one after that. The parser triggers the error as soon as it sees something that causes an actual syntax error (like EOF in this case, or the beginning of the next line in other cases).

Comment: Could it for some reason be sending a `\r`?  That's odd...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments I gather that you are getting the error when leaving out the closing bracket of a function call.

The odd display is not a terminal error, Python does not raise a syntax error until it realizes that the bracket is not there, which can happen several lines below in your code as function calls are allowed to span multiple lines.

Here, you probably have something on the line (7) after the one where python raises a SyntaxError. Python expected a closing bracket before, so it highlights the very last character of the line before, which is the last valid spot for the (missing) bracket.

Comment: you don't need a blank line, [example](http://ideone.com/8maMu). Notice that `^` points to the end of the comment.